# Error when downloading images from Sky Server database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, error-handling, urllib

I'm working on collecting images from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey, and trying to download these images locally to a folder. This is the code I have so far:

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

def get_images(df_converted):
    objid_list = df_converted['OBJID'].tolist()
    ra_list = df_converted['RA_DECIMAL'].tolist()
    dec_list = df_converted['DEC_DECIMAL'].tolist()

    for objid, ra, dec in zip(objid_list, ra_list, dec_list):
        # Save the image using the 'OBJID' as .jpg image
        filename = str(objid) + '.jpg'
        # Replace the ra and dec coordinates in the URL, downloading in 512 x 512 resolution
        image_url = "http://skyservice.pha.jhu.edu/DR7/ImgCutout/getjpeg.aspx?ra=" + str(ra) + "&dec=" + str(dec) + "&scale=0.40&width=512&height=512&opt="
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, "images/" + filename)
```

This code works fine and I am able to download roughly 600 images, but these aren't all the images I need. At some point, I run into the following error:

```
shilpakancharla@Shilpas-MBP galaxy-classification % python3 sdss_image_capture.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 928, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sdss_image_capture.py", line 87, in <module>
    get_images(new_df)
  File "sdss_image_capture.py", line 82, in get_images
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, "images/" + filename)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1345, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>
```

I'm having some trouble understanding the `Transfer-encoding` part of the error and why that is occurring, and how I could write my method in such a way that it is able to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution through:

`pip install ssl`

and then adding the following lines to my code:

`import ssl` and
`ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context` in my driver code.